# How can I can not find a user with spaces in their names?

Tags: search

I try to search 
user:"Nam Gi VU"
But I got no results, how can I search using this name? 
(The name can be any names, I just get my name as an example.

Comment: Are you talking about searching on StackOverflow?  I can find you fine...

Comment: Searching what?  Using what programming language?

Comment: "You put your right foot in, / You put your right foot out; / You put your right foot in / then you shake it all about"

Comment: Sorry everyone, I suppose to post this question on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here since you haven't specified a lot about the environment.

If you're running on a UNIXy-type box, you can simply use something like:

```
egrep -i '^nam +gi +vu$' /path/to/usernames.txt
```

The `+` indicates one or more of the preceding character so it will find the words `nam`, `gi` and `vu` with spaces between them (the `-i` means ignore case).

If you're allowed to have spaces at the start and end, use:

```
egrep -i '^ *nam +gi +vu *$' /path/to/usernames.txt
```

(`*` means zero or more of the preceding character).

If you have a more advanced regex tool, you can use `\s` for white space and `\b` for word boundaries.

Comment: The trouble with taking a shot in the dark is that you frequently shoot yourself in the foot :-) Here's hoping that's not the case here.